# Markdown parser, template engine, and then some

Tags: python, python-2.x, template, markdown

I've got my own website! Woo! It's got HTML and everything! But after struggling for a while with HTML and keeping my navbar consistent across pages, I gave up and wrote a program which:

- Searches for every markdown file in the given root directory or below.
- Parses it into HTML with [mistune](https://github.com/lepture/mistune), which thankfully only needs the one file to work
- Inserts it into a given template file which contains stuff like a navbar and a footer
- Looks for a similarly-named `.js` or `.css` file and links those if appropriate
- Looks for a `page-title` thing at the beginning and sets the title to that if it exists
- Puts it all together into a `.html` file
- Searches through the `.html` file for any URLs which point to the root of the site and modifies them to point to the *real* root if, like me, your content is hosted in a subdirectory
- Writes all that fun stuff to the hard drive for Apache to read

In short, it mashes everything together for a website that actually looks pretty good.

```
# Configuration options:
# =====================

# Where are the files to parse located? (generally ~/www)
# Don't include the trailing slash.
ROOT_PATH = "/home/MY_USERNAME/www"

# Is your site hosted at some prefix? Set ROOT_URL to wherever
# that is and all the URLs which start from root (i.e. start
# with "/") will have it prepended. No trailing slash.
ROOT_URL = "/MY_USERNAME"

# Suppress logging if in fast mode to speed it up some
DEBUG_MODE = False

# ================ #
# Code starts here #
# Do not modify it #
# ================ #

# Imports not at the top because that way it's JUST configuration
# stuff up there.
from glob import glob
import mistune, os, re, sys, time


def log(a):
    if DEBUG_MODE:
        print(a)


def root_sub(m):
    url = m.group(0)
    if url.startswith(ROOT_URL):
        print("    Found URL starting with site root! Change it!")
        return url
    if url.startswith("/"):
        log("    Prepending site root to URL")
        return ROOT_URL + url
    else:
        log("    URL is relative; not prepending site root")
        return url


def parse(page, style_path, script_path):
    # Page styles
    style_tag = ""
    if style_path:
        log("  Adding style path to file")
        style_tag = "<link href=\"{}\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />"\
                    .format(os.path.basename(style_path))
    else:
        log("  No style file found")

    # Page scripts
    script_tag = ""
    if script_path:
        log("  Adding script path to file")
        script_tag = "<script src=\"{}\" />"\
                     .format(os.path.basename(script_path))
    else:
        log("  No script file found")

    # Page title
    match = re.search(r"^page-title: ?(.*?)$", page, re.M)
    if match:
        log("  Extracting title")
        title_tag = "<title>" + match.group(1) + "</title>"
        page = page[:match.start()] + page[match.end():]
    else:
        log("  No title found; defaulting to 'Untitled Page'")
        title_tag = "<title>Untitled Page</title>"

    # Writing the data
    log("  Parsing markdown")
    parsed = md(page)
    log("  Performing template replacement")
    templated = (template  # This odd formatting makes it easy to reorder/add
                 .replace("[[version]]", version)
                 .replace("[[style-tag]]", style_tag)
                 .replace("[[script-tag]]", script_tag)
                 .replace("[[title-tag]]", title_tag)
                 .replace("[[markdown]]", parsed)
                )
    if (ROOT_URL and ROOT_URL != "/"):
        log("  Performing link modification...")
        templated = re.sub(r'href="/', r'href="{}/'.format(ROOT_URL),
                           templated)
        log("  Done")
    else:
        log("  Root is just the normal root; no prepending needed.")
    return templated


# Setup
version = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d")
print("Publishing version {}".format(version))
md = mistune.Markdown()
files = list(glob(ROOT_PATH + "/**/*.md")) + list(glob(ROOT_PATH + "/*.md"))
template_path = "./_template.html"
log("Template file at {}".format(template_path))
log("Files to parse: {}".format(", ".join(files)))
log("Reading template file data")
with open(template_path) as template_file:
    template = template_file.read()

for i in range(0, len(files)):
    # Per-file setup
    path = files[i]
    path_base = path[0:-3]  # This is safe because we know it's always .md
    out_path = path_base + ".html"
    if not DEBUG_MODE:
        print("Parsing {}/{}: {}".format(i + 1, len(files), path))
    log("Parsing {} -> {}...".format(path, out_path))
    log("  Calculating paths")
    style_path = path_base + ".css"
    log("  Searching for stylesheet at {}".format(style_path))
    script_path = path_base + ".js"
    log("  Searching for scripts at {}".format(script_path))

    # Markdown reading
    log("  Reading Markdown from file...")
    log("    Opening file for reading")
    with open(path, "r") as parsing:
        log("    Reading data")
        raw = parsing.read()
        log("  Done")

        parsed = parse(raw,
                       style_path if os.path.isfile(style_path) else None,
                       script_path if os.path.isfile(script_path) else None)

        log("  Writing output to file...")
        log("    Opening file for output")
        with open(out_path, "w") as out:
            log("    Writing data")
            out.write(parsed)
        log("  Done")
        log("Done")

print("Completed parsing for version {}.".format(version))
```

I'm mostly concerned about

- **Efficiency** -- Both in terms of speed and memory. I'm especially concerned about the constant calls to `log` -- if it's not in debug mode, do these have any overhead, or does Python ignore them because it can tell that the function doesn't do anything?
- **Readability** -- I tried to make the code understandable, but in places it's confusing.
- **Fewer long, long blocks of code** -- like the `parse` function, which I can't figure out how to reasonably split into pieces.
- **Safety** -- Does my URL replacement only happen when I expect it to (i.e. in URLs, or stuff that looks reasonably like one)? What about my `page-title` searching?

I'm not at all concerned about

- Perfect compliance with PEP8 -- there are a bunch of guidelines that I simply don't care about, because they don't make sense to me. Feel free to point out violations, but I've run this through a validator and fixed the things I cared about, so anything left over is irrelevant to me.
- Cross-platform functioning -- this is a nice bonus, but frankly unnecessary, since I'll probably never use a non-Unix box.

Note: I'm strictly limited to Python 2.7.5 by the server I'm working on -- I can't install 3 or even a newer version of 2.

Answer (score 2):

## One-lining `log`

Your `log` method can become this:

```
print(a) if DEBUG_MODE else None
```

This requires either python 3 or an import: `from __future__ import print_function`

## Unnecessary parens

```
if (ROOT_URL and ROOT_URL != "/")
```

You don't need the brackets/parens around that conditional, there are only two conditions.

## `range`

`range(0, len(files))` can just be `range(len(files))`, because range starts at 0 by default. The syntax is essentially `range(start=0, stop, step=1)` - the only mandatory param is `stop`.

## Filename parsing

If you want to parse filenames by yourself rather than using a library, then while your current solution:

```
path_base = path[0:-3]
```

is *technically* safe, and is fine for your current script, but if you want to adapt it for another script, it'll break. A more general, equivalent one-liner is:

```
path_base = ".".join(path.split('.')[0:-1])
```

## String replacement

If you've got a lot of replacements, or you plan on adding more, try an extensible solution instead of all the `replace` calls:

```
replacements = {
    'version': version,
    'style-tag': style_tag,
    'script_tag': script_tag,
    'title-tag': title_tag,
    'markdown': parsed
}
templated = template
for repl_name, repl_val in replacements.iteritems():
    templated.replace('[[{}]]'.format(repl_name), repl_value)
```

Comment: `print(a) if DEBUG_MODE` won't work. Are you thinking of Ruby?

Comment: @200_success Entirely possible. I've added the else clause, so it works now (verified locally).